# Is np.fft.fft working properly? I am getting very large frequency values

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, fft

I'm trying to do some audio cleaning, which I have never done before using python or otherwise and I came across the idea that I could use FFT to find the frequencies that make up my audio and eliminate the frequencies that don't belong. i did it on normal audio, but I couldn't understand the results, so I tried it on a simple sine wave.

I made it

```
frequency = 1000

num_samples = 48000

# The sampling rate of the analog to digital convert

sampling_rate = 48000.0
sine_wave = [np.sin(2 * np.pi * frequency * x1 / sampling_rate) for x1 in range(num_samples)]
sine_wave = np.array(sine_wave)
```

Then I played and plotted it and it looked and sounded like a normal size wave.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,3))
ax.plot(sine_wave[:500])
IPython.display.Audio(data=sine_wave, rate=44100)
```

But when I did fft and looked at the frequencies on a graph it didn't make sense

```
def do_fft(data_samples):  
    data_fft = np.fft.fft(data_samples)
    freq = (np.abs(data_fft[:len(data_fft)]))
    plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))
    plt.plot(freq)
    print("The frequency is {} Hz".format(np.argmax(freq)))
    return freq

sine_freq = do_fft(sine_wave)
sine_freq[47000]
```

For one, I don't really understand what my frequency array is supposed to mean. I know that a high number at a certain index *K* means that *K* Hz appears a lot in the sound. This would make sense since I got a value of like 23,999.99999 at 1000 Hz, which is what my wave frequency is. What doesn't make sense is that I got 24,000 for 47,000 Hz. That doesn't make any sense to me. Did I do something wrong? Is fft not working properly?

Comment: I wanted to close this question as duplicate, but there are so many duplicates I don’t even know which one to pick... Please read a few of [these Q&As](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+how+to+interpret+fft) for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

The FFT of strictly real (all imaginary components == zero) data is always conjugate mirror symmetric.  That's just the way the math of an FFT works.  So your 47kHz peak (the same as -1kHz) is just the mirror image of 1kHz at a 48k sample rate.  The Nyquist folding frequency or mirroring hinge is at half the sample rate (and/or zero if you consider the upper bin frequencies negative).

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to explicitly define time and calculate the frequencies. The FT should be plotted against those frequencies. The `argmax` alone computes the place in a vector, not a frequency.
A sampling rate (sa/sec) is not a frequency. The Nyquist theorem states (among others) that your maximum frequency (in Hz) is 1/2 the sampling rate in Sa/sec. 
Since we are using the complex FT (pos. and neg. frequencies shown), the -999.979 Hz is actually +1000 Hz.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as p

sampling_rate = 48000 

t= np.linspace(0,1,sampling_rate+1)       # time vector
dt=t[1]-t[0]
print(f'first/last time {t[0]}, {t[-1]}')
print(f'time interval : {dt}')


f = 1000
sig = np.sin(2 * np.pi * f*t)

fig = p.figure(figsize=(15,10))
p.subplot(211)
p.plot(sig[:500])

p.subplot(212)
ft = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(sig))
freq=np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fftfreq(len(t),dt))
p.plot(freq,ft )
print(f'argmax of FT is not a frequency, but a position in a vector : {np.argmax(ft)}')
f0=freq[np.argmax(ft)]
print(f'the frequency is {f0:.3f} Hz')
```

[image]

Comment: I'm a little confused here. What is your ft variable? What does that represent? What is np.fft.fftshift doing? Can you also explain what you did to get your freq variable. Also, you plotted freq to ft. Why is there a negative? Why are there 2 bars?

Comment: there are four variables:  time `t`,  amplitude in time `sig`, frequency `freq` and amplitude in frequency space `ft` . There are two bars because of the definition of the  DFT, which allows negative frequencies. The amplitudes of these negative frequencies are identical to the ones for positive frequencies, so you could just plot the right half w/o losing information. Check it out by printing a few of  the 'freq' and 'ft` values. Also see @hotpaw2 note.

Comment: fftshift is a rotation(Mathematica) or rolling (Numpy) of the frequency vector. The FT w/o fftshift starts at 0 frequency and goes to max (Nyquist) in the middle, then starts over at the middle with the negative Nyquist frequency and goes to 0 frequency at the end.  That's a result of the inplace FFT operation. You could just take the first half and would be fine (no. neg. frequencies). But the negative frequencies are useful in many physics situations (eg. diffraction). I tried to stay general so I use all the FFT provides, but as @hotpaw said, for your case you don't need neg. freq.